# How can I visualize real-time Linux system information like the output of command top?

Tags: linux

I want to implement a simple demo that can visualize *real-time* system load, my requirement is really simple, just to get the data of command top is enough.

But I'm not sure how to get the real-time data, should I grep the output or read from *file system*, could anyone provide some clues on how to get the *real-time data*?

thkx!

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know how to run top, the data in top is sufficient, how can you not get the data if you get the data? You may want to rephrase what you're asking ...

Comment: oh, I don't know how to parse and extract the output of command top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the output from top is certainly enough to visualize realtime system load. For general realtime system information, you might want to take a look at the [`/proc` virtual filesystem](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html), which contains information exposed by the kernel. This is also in easily parsible tabular form.